# Batch request to get presence of multiple subscribed contacts using UCWA 2.0 API

Tags: rest, ucwa

We are using UCWA 2.0 API to subscribe to the presence of selected contacts. We followed the steps as mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/ucwa/subscribetothepresenceofselectedcontacts)

After event channel is open, we are getting list of URL to get presence of each contact.

Can we use Batching request to get the presence of all the listed contacts at once?

If yes, We tried to execute the batch request but we are facing 400 Bad request error.

What we have tried is here :

```
POST /ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/102452001887/batch
```

Headers :

```
Authorization:Bearer <access_token>

Accept:multipart/batching

Host:webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com

Content-Type:multipart/batching; boundary="77f2569d"

with Body:

{

--77f2569d

Content-Type: application/http;msgtype=request

GET /ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/102452001887/people/user2@orgabc.onmicrosoft.com/presence HTTP/1.1

Host: lyncweb.contoso.com

Accept: application/json

--77f2569d

Content-Type: application/http; msgtype=request

GET /ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/102452001887/people/user3@orgabc.onmicrosoft.com/presence HTTP/1.1

Host: lyncweb.contoso.com

Accept: application/json

--77f2569d

}
```

I have also tried to add headers as mentioned in UCWA 2.0 API document but still facing the same issue.

Could you please suggest if we are missing something and how can we process the batch request.

Comment: What library are you using to create/send your batch message?  My initial thoughts are that you have an incorrectly formatted batch message and you may be missing additional line endings/carriage returns which may seem unnecessary.  I would suggest playing around with a network capturing tool like Fiddler and play around with the message until you can get the format exactly correct.

Comment: Would you please format your post properly?

Comment: I am following this .link(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/ucwa/batchingrequests)

Answer (score 0):

[image] At the end of the last item requested you need a "--" example: --77f2569d--

```
Content-Type: application/http; msgtype=request
GET /ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/102452001887/people/user3@orgabc.onmicrosoft.com/presence HTTP/1.1
Host: lyncweb.contoso.com

Accept: application/json

--77f2569d--
```